# Can I make a WPF style take precedence over a local value?

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles

I have created a boolean attached property in my WPF project, and I want elements with this property set to true to display a certain way, regardless of any local local values that have been set in the XAML.

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx), I understand that by default, local values take precedence over both style setters and style triggers. Is it possible to create a style trigger that takes precedence over local values?

Comment: I am not aware of such techniques, but I know you can do a lot of subclassing and coding to get the effects you want. There is also simpler way, using animations. You can do pretty much anything with DiscreteObjectKeyFrame and animation has higher precedence than anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the technique mentioned by Erti-Chris Eelmaa in his comment on my question, I ended up creating an animation which did the trick:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="my:Ext.IsReadOnly" Value="True">
            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard Name="IsReadOnly">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.IsEnabled)" Duration="0:0:0">
                            <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame Value="False" KeyTime="0:0:0" />
                        </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.EnterActions>
            <Trigger.ExitActions>
                <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="IsReadOnly" />
            </Trigger.ExitActions>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

This takes precedence over any local value for `Button.IsEnabled`.