# How to override inline style in xaml

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2015

I have a TabControl which is bound to ViewModel. I want to set the margin of the auto generated TabPanel, but I am unable to do so, because I think the style is set inline via TabControl's implementation...

Here is my style...

```
<TabControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabPanel}">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="14,0,0,0" />
    </Style>
</TabControl.Resources>
```

and the resulting style using Visual Studio's Live Property Explorer is like this...

[image]

UPDATE 1:

Here is the `XAML` for ItemTemplate that generates the `TabPanel` itself:

```
<TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="150" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Source="{Binding ImageUri}" 
                   Height="25" Width="35" Margin="0,0,0,10" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding TestName}" TextAlignment="Center" 
                       TextWrapping="Wrap" FontFamily="Open Sans" FontWeight="Regular" FontSize="14" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</TabControl.ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override the TabControl template to customize the appearance. In this case you will be responsible for designing template, but also will be able to customize it in a way you like.

Example template is taken from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.tabpanel(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="" Width="500" Height="500">
<Window.Resources>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle"
                Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels"
                Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
                    <Grid KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                                                      Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FFAAAAAA" />
                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <TabPanel x:Name="HeaderPanel"
                                  Grid.Row="0"
                                  Panel.ZIndex="1"
                                  Margin="14,0,4,0"
                                  IsItemsHost="True"
                                  KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1"
                                  Background="Transparent" />
                        <Border x:Name="Border"
                                Grid.Row="1"
                                BorderThickness="1"
                                CornerRadius="2"
                                KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local"
                                KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained"
                                KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="2">
                            <Border.Background>
                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1"
                                                     StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                    <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ContentAreaColorLight}" Offset="0" />
                                    <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ContentAreaColorDark}" Offset="1" />
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Border.Background>
                            <Border.BorderBrush>
                                <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource BorderMediumColor}" />
                            </Border.BorderBrush>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_SelectedContentHost" Margin="4" ContentSource="SelectedContent" />
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

</Window.Resources>
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}">
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="150" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding .}" TextAlignment="Center"
                           TextWrapping="Wrap" FontFamily="Open Sans" FontWeight="Regular" FontSize="14" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. It solved my problem with minor tweaks, but isn't there a shorter solution for this ? Like `!important` in CSS. I guess there should be one.

Comment: @NaveedButt AFAIK, WPF styles are different from CSS styles. They are not really cascading, so only **one** style is applied to the element at once and it should have no conflicting attributes. !important in css is used in junction with cascading to give max weight when conflicts occurs. Still, you might have a **[precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx)** issue, like you had now, and wpf just follow the rules described in the link. Btw, **[here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16008484/5246145)** is a similar question, but I dont think that tecnique is better