# c# wpf Style Control in UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I have a MainWindow with an UserControl. I want to change the background of the ListBox which is in the UserControl. But the Style is only applied to the UserControl and not on the inner Control.

*Later I want to modifiy the ListBoxItems from extern..*

#### MainWindow

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="279.716" Width="279.784"
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
<Window.Resources>

</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:UserControl1}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"></Setter>
            <Style.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"></Setter>
                </Style>
            </Style.Resources>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <local:UserControl1 Margin="47,22,34,46"></local:UserControl1>
</Grid>
```

#### XAML

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid>
    <ListBox Background="Aqua" x:Name="listBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="192" Margin="54,44,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="192"/>

</Grid>
```

[image: Preview]

Comment: local value (`<ListBox Background="Aqua" ...`) has higher priority than Style setter value

Comment: @ASh thank you! This is the problem. Is there a way to have another "initalvalue" and the possibility to override it?

Comment: create a special DependencyPropery in `UserControl1` of type `Brush` with a desired default value and bind `ListBox Background` to that property using TemplateBinding. it should work and you won't need a style for ListBox in UserControl1.Resources because it can be set directly via style setter

Comment: ..and when I want to change the Background of the ListBoxItems? A Collection is bound to the UserControl on my parent window and I want to modify these Items by a property value. I don't want to code these Triggers in the XAML code of the UserControl, because I would like to use it as an universal control.

Comment: ListBox has ItemContainerStyle property which is used for styling its ListBoxItems. it would be handy to expose that property in UserControl1 and use it in xaml, but I'm not sure which is the best way to do it. try look what is `AddOwner` method and use it on ItemContainerStyle property

Comment: ok thank you @ASh. btw here is a trick to avoid the priority http://stackoverflow.com/a/16009672/6229375

Answer (score 1):

You actually don't need a style for that. You have to bind the background property of the ListBox to the background property of the UserControl :

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestAppWPFStackOverFlow.UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestAppWPFStackOverFlow"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid>
    <ListBox Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=Background}" x:Name="listBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="192" Margin="54,44,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="192"/>
</Grid>
```

and the caller should look like :

```
 <Window x:Class="TestAppWPFStackOverFlow.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestAppWPFStackOverFlow"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <local:UserControl1 Margin="47,22,34,46" Background="Brown"></local:UserControl1>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And the result is :

[image]

If you want to use a style for all your custom controls for background, you should use this section of code (after you apply the suggested approach):

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:UserControl1}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"></Setter>
        </Style>
```

Now, if you want to change the background of the items it is a little bit more complicated. You have to create a style for the *ListBoxItem* item which should look like below :

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
        </Style>
```

But you probably want to control the color from outside the control, so you need a dependency property.

In UserControl1.xaml.cs you have to define :

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsBackgroundProperty =
          DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsBackground", typeof(string), typeof(UserControl1),
              new FrameworkPropertyMetadata());


        public string ItemsBackground
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(ItemsBackgroundProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ItemsBackgroundProperty, value); }
        }
```

And the style will be modified to use this property :

```
   <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                                                                     AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}},
                                      Path=ItemsBackground}" />
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>
```

Now, the only thing that you have to set is this property when you use your control :

```
 <local:UserControl1 Margin="47,22,34,46" ItemsBackground="Yellow" ></local:UserControl1>
```

The result :

[image]